# Changing balloon text with Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails

I'm using Gmaps4rails to display a google map in my rails application.  I have a list of locations displayed correctly on the map, but when I click one of the points, the balloon which pops up doesn't show the information I want displayed.  I don't think it would be hard to change the data/format of the balloon information, but I can't find where this balloon information is stored!

What files within Gmaps4rails define what information is displayed in the balloon when a point on the map is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You must redefine `gmaps4rails_infowindow` method in your model, for example:

```
  def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<h1>#{self.name}</h1><p>#{self.address}</p><p>#{self.description}</p>"
  end
```

[Security Warning](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Security-Warning)